# set-fontset-font only overrides some Unicode character ranges (OS X)

Tags: macos, unicode, emacs, fonts

If I put the following into a scratch buffer (running `emacs -q` on 24.4.1), I can get the symbols (those in the comment) to change by varying the font name (changing the size so that it becomes `"MS PGothic-24"` for example). This is nice, and seems to show `set-fontset-font` working as intended.

```
; multiset symbols (unions with stuff inside them: ⊌ ⊎ 
(set-fontset-font t '(#x228C . #x228E) "MS PGothic-22")
```

However, if I have

```
; greek alphabet: α β γ δ
(set-fontset-font t '(#x370 . #x3F0) "MS PGothic-22")
```

then I seem to be trapped in a Menlo font. If I put cursor on the character and do `C-u C-x =`, I get output including the following:

```
mac-ct:-*-Menlo-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x2F9)
```

The rest of the output confirms that the character I'm looking at is in the given range:

```
        character: α (displayed as α) (codepoint 945, #o1661, #x3b1)
```

By contrast, the output for the union-symbols is

```
mac-ct:-*-MS PGothic-normal-normal-normal-*-22-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1 (#x43A0)
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question about `set-fontset-font`. But if you just need an alternative then you can try `enlarge-font` (to shrink or enlarge) in [`frame-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el). It uses `x-decompose-font-name` and `x-compose-font-name`. See function `frcmds-enlarged-font-name`.

Comment: It's really just certain characters within the frame that I want to be different.

Comment: Try adjusting your start and maybe end characters. The character #x370 doesn't actually exist in the version of MS PGothic that I have (nor in most other fonts), and this may be affecting emacs's decision on whether to actually use that font for the range specified.  #374 seems to be the first widely supported character from the Greek range, so I'd give that a go.  The code you posted above does work on Windows though, so the problem could be something else.

Comment: I tried using `(#x3B1 . #x3B4)` (for lowercase alpha to delta only), and this didn't help.  The characters stayed resolutely Menlo.

Comment: For what it's worth this issue no longer arises with at least emacs 26.1.